# Gradle jettyRun doesn't stop in intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, jetty, intellij-13

We had a Maven project that was using JettyRun beautifully in IntelliJ, by that I mean that you would start the build, even debug and then just stop the build (with the red button) and it was stopping jetty too.

We had to move to Gradle and we thought of using gradle JettyRun plugin, but it doesn't work in the same way. In fact if you stop the build, jetty will keep running in background and I have to kill it manually from the terminal.

The configuration is simply:

```
apply plugin: 'jetty'

...

jettyRun {
    contextPath = ""
}
```

does anybody know how to have the old maven's behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself the solution (sort of): the jetty plugin does have a `jettyStop` task that will definitely terminate the server.

To automate this I did (**EDIT: thanks to dschulz**):

```
stopPort = 9123
stopKey = "jjj" //whatever you prefere
//Stops the jetty Instace when restarting (instance has to be stopped manually otherwise, with jettyStop)
jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.daemon = true
[jettyRun, jettyRunWar].each { jetty ->
    jetty.dependsOn jettyStop
}
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it doesn't works as expected. However, I deleted the `<<` part in `jetty.dependsOn << jettyStop` and now it's working fine. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Oh, and I needed this too: `[jettyRun, jettyRunWar]*.daemon = true`. Otherwise it's not possible to stop Jetty from IntelliJ.